# Java logging levels confusion

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I set logging level to CONFIG, but don't see messages written on CONFIG level. What I am missing?

Configuration:

```
Logger logger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("xxx");
logger.setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.CONFIG);
```

Tests:

```
logger.log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, "severe");
logger.log(java.util.logging.Level.WARNING, "warning");
logger.log(java.util.logging.Level.INFO, "info");
logger.log(java.util.logging.Level.CONFIG, "config");
logger.log(java.util.logging.Level.FINE, "fine");
logger.log(java.util.logging.Level.FINER, "finer");
logger.log(java.util.logging.Level.FINEST, "finest");
```

Output:

```
SEVERE: severe
WARNING: warning
INFO: info
```

Comment: Which did you actually set your log level to, `INFO` or `CONFIG`? Your question contains conflicting information.

Comment: Ups, sorry. I set the log level to CONFIG.

Comment: The important thing to set is the "root logger" level. The root logger  is represented by the empty string: `Logger rootlogger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("");`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I typically use [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) to implement logging, which seems a tad better documented. So I would recommend switching to that.

But to answer your question, I think what is happening is that your `Logger` is configured correctly, but the `Handler` it's sending its messages to isn't. The default configuration probably attaches a handler with `INFO` level logging to the root logger.

edit: I wrote a little test program to verify, you indeed need to set the level on the handler attached to the root logger. You can do so like this:

```
for (Handler handler : Logger.getLogger("").getHandlers()) {
    handler.setLevel(Level.CONFIG);
}
logger.config("config");
```

Gives as output:

> Feb 11, 2011 4:32:14 PM Test main
>   CONFIG: config

This sets the level for all handlers attached to this. Obviously a better choice would be writing your own options file and explicitly configuring your loggers. A quick google turned up [this article](http://www.crazysquirrel.com/computing/java/logging.jspx) on the subject.

You could also try configuring with a properties file on your classpath that reads:

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=CONFIG
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior.

When you define a level of logs, you will see all the logs of this level, but also the ones linked to higher level.

The order is the following:

- SEVERE (highest value)
- WARNING
- INFO
- CONFIG
- FINE
- FINER
- FINEST (lowest value)

So in your case, if you define the level to `INFO`, you will only see `SEVERE`, `WARNING` and `INFO` logs, and not `CONFIG` messages.

---

**Edit**, to answer your corrected question:

Maybe a third party library is used for your `Logger` class (log4j, slf4j, and so on), and this library defines its own level of log. For example, for log4j, there are only the following levels:

- DEBUG
- INFO
- WARN
- ERROR
- FATAL

In such case, the level `CONFIG` is considered as a `INFO` level, that explains your current behavior.

Comment: The OP did not set the level to `INFO`, however. He set it to `CONFIG`. **edit** okay, there's actually conflicting info in the question. His english says "I set the log level to `INFO`" but his code says `logger.setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.CONFIG);`

Comment: yes, indeed, it is not clear. I considered the first sentence, not the code just below...

Comment: Sorry for confusion, fixed the question.

Comment: @romaintaz, I just created a simple java program, and dropped my experimental code in it. And still see SEVERE, WARNING, INFO. May be default implementation also has different levels?

Comment: @alex2k8 Just tried your code in a simple Java code, and indeed, I get the same result as yours...